# React Native AsyncStorage returns promise even used await and async

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I researched the problem in AsyncStorage.getItem. Many of comment said we should apply **await** and **anync** on AsyncStorage, such as

[React Native AsyncStorage returns promise instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843305/react-native-asyncstorage-returns-promise-instead-of-value/42843802?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

[AsyncStorage.getItem returning promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916507/asyncstorage-getitem-returning-promise?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

However, it still return Promise to me like the snapshot below. Inside this Promise, **_55** contained correct user information. Would every people help me figure out the problem and give me possible solution? Thank You!

Snapshot:
[Debugger snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ji9i.png)

Reducer:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from "react-native";
import {LOGIN, LOGOUT, UPDATE} from './../actions/authActions'
import user from "./index";

export type State = {
    user: Object,
    login: boolean,
}

getUser = async (string) => {  //Get user information form AsyncStorage
    try {
         return await AsyncStorage.getItem(string)
                  .then((user) => {
                     if (user !== null) {
                        return JSON.parse(user);
                     } else {
                        return null;
                   }
                });
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
};

const initialState = {
    info: getUser(),
    login: !!this.info, // if not null, login = ture
};

function loginReducer(state: State = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN:
            return {
                info: action.payload,
                login: true,
            };
        case LOGOUT:
            return {
                info: null,
                login: false,
            };
        case UPDATE:
            return {...state, info: Object.assign(state.info, action.payload)};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Action:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from "react-native";
import {requestLogIn, requestLogOut} from "../../config/api/authApi"

export const LOGIN = "LOGIN";
export const LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";
export const UPDATE = "UPDATE";
export const ERROR = "ERROR";

export function login(user) {
    return dispatch => {
        return AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user)) //Store user information in AsyncStorage
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN,
                    payload: user
                })
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.warn("Error: ", error);
                dispatch({
                    type: ERROR,
                    payload: null
                })
            });
    }
}

export function logout(token) { //
    return dispatch => {
        return requestLogOut(token).then((status) => {
            if (status) {
                return AsyncStorage.removeItem("user")
                    .then(() => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: LOGOUT,
                        })
                    }).catch(() => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: ERROR,
                            payload: null
                        });
                    });
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: ERROR,
                    payload: null
                });
            }
        })

    }
} ..// other actions
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getUser` is an `async` function, but you're not `await`ing it:

```
const initialState = {
    info: getUser(),      // <=== here
    login: !!this.info,
};
```

`async` functions return promises.

Without getting into the broader context of the code too much, you probably want to do something like this:

```
const initialState = {
    info: null,
    login: !!this.info,
};
getUser().then(info => initialState.info = info);
```

Or something along those lines. Note that that means `initialState.info` will be `null` until the storage returns the value. If you have more initialization that needs that value, you'll have to trigger it from the `then` handler above.

(No `catch` on that because you've defined `getUser` such that it cannot reject.)